# Generate Url in MVC from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Lets say i`m in an action method and i want to generate a string like this :

```
http://www.myhost.com/Home/Index?Id=1
```

i want to save this to DB so i was wondering if there is any formal way to generate it instead of building it up myself.

I`m using MVC3

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url.aspx) property of the controller:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    string url = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = 1 });
    // TODO: save to DB
}
```

and if you need an absolute url just use the proper overload:

```
string url = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = 1 }, "http");
```

Comment: funny thing is the only Url i have is under System.Security.Policy; and it doesn't have Action Method

Comment: @Stacker, the code example I have shown is inside a controller action. Controller actions belong to a controller. Controllers derive from the Controller class. The Controller class has an Url property. This is what you should use. You should not try to generate urls just anywhere in your application which is what I suppose you are doing, like in the Model for example. If some part of your code needs an url, you should generate this url in the controller and pass it as parameter to this part of the code that needs it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I know this is off-topic for this answer, but how would you unit test Foo()? Wouldn't you need to mock the HttpContext / HttpRequest?

Comment: @olivehour, yes, exactly, you will mock the HttpContext.